# How to sum items in a table if their FK appears more than once?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In a table such as this:

```
FK-----Value
01-----100
02-----50
02-----150
03-----50
03-----50
```

How can I query it to show as

```
FK-----Value
01-----100
02-----200
03-----100
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean "02---150" and not "02---200"? If you do actually mean that, can you explain what the pattern is?

Comment: shouldn't 02 be 200 instead of 150?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT FK, SUM(VALUE)
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY FK
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sum:

```
SELECT FK,SUM(Value)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FK;
```

For Max:

```
SELECT FK,MAX(Value)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FK;
```